# Lightweight Migration to copy attribute content

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

the problem is that I want  to release new version of my .xcdatamodel,  I  want rename an attribute (no problem) but in addition I want to add a new attribute  with contents of one existint, something like that:

old version
attribute name: "mobile"

new version:
attribute name: "phoneCall" (before "mobile") (no problem for do it with Lightweight Migration)
new attribute: "phoneSMS" (I want inizialize this attribute with the contents of  "mobile" (or "phoneCall" new version)

The question is: I can do that using Lightweight Migration? I could use "Default Value" o "Reg. Ex" in Attribute Details to initialize "phoneSMS". I need look around Standard Migrations?

Answer (score 1):

In order to copy values from another column, you probably do want to look at a standard migration and compose a mapping as well as an entity migration class to handle getting the correct value for you. So yeah; Standard Migrations is your way.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott, I will look around of Apple Core Data Programming Guide (again)

Comment: No problem. Incidentally, this book really helped me (and I know that Marcus is a user in stack overflow too). Lists as "out of print", but maybe he'd know how you could get an online copy: http://pragprog.com/book/mzcd/core-data

Comment: Scott, thank you very much for the recommendation looks like a book that can help me.